# PowerShell printing only first letter of a string

Tags: string, powershell, array-indexing

I have a PowerShell script that connects to a localhost API that returns a dictionary of "sessions" and whether they are active

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://localhost:44356/api/RDM/getSessions' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
$numOfUsers = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://localhost:44356/api/RDM/countSessions' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
for($x = 0; $x -lt $numOfUsers; $x++)
{
$user = $response.userId[$x]
$name = $response.sessionName[$x]
"`nSession Name: $name"
"User Logged In: $user`n"
}
pause
```

When more than one session is active it returns correctly:

```
Session Name: ExampleSession
User Logged In: ExampleUser
```

But when only 1 is active it returns only the first letter:

```
Session Name: E
User Logged In: E
```

I do know that this bug is caused by the script and not the API, however so far I am unable to find the source of the problem.

Comment: this is one reason that i prefer to use the `foreach` loop structure instead of the `for` loop. the 1st handles things one at a time by its very nature ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, true in general, but if you need to iterate over _multiple_ collections, `foreach` doesn't help. For a related discussion, see [GitHub proposal #14724](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14724).

Comment: that seems to be what `for` is for ... but i do agree that letting PoSh handle the nitty-gritty indexing stuff is an interesting thing. not sure it is worth it, tho. thank you for the link! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Letting PowerShell handle the nitty-gritty of iteration is why you advocated for `foreach` here. I pointed out that, because in this case _multiple_ collections are to be iterated over, `foreach` is currently _not_ an option. [This comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14724#issuecomment-774709735) on the linked GitHub issue in particular suggests a way in which `foreach` could be enhanced to also cover this use case, using the _hypothetical_ (as of v7.1) syntax `foreach ($user, $name in $response.userId, $response.sessionName) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implication is that if only *one* session is returned, `$response.userId` and `$response.sessionName` are not *one-element arrays* but just *strings* - and indexing into strings returns *characters* (e.g., `'foo'[0]` returns `'f'`).<sup>[1]</sup>

You can use `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) to ensure that you're always dealing with *arrays*:

```
$user = @($response.userId)[$x]
$name = @($response.sessionName)[$x]
```

If the count of sessions can be large, the following performs better (because `@(...)` creates a (shallow) *copy* of an array<sup>[2]</sup>, whereas an `[array]` cast uses an existing array as-is):

```
$user = ([array] $response.userId)[$x]
$name = ([array] $response.sessionName)[$x]
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that, unlike in C#, the character returned is technically also a *string* (`[string]`, [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String)), not a `[char]` ([`System.Char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Char)) instance, because PowerShell itself doesn't use the `[char]` type.</sup>

<sup>[2] In older PowerShell versions (up to v5.0), this also applied to arrays with explicitly enumerated elements; e.g., `@('foo', 'bar')`, but this case has since been optimized to accommodate the widespread practice of using such expressions to define array *literals* - even though the `@(...)` isn't strictly needed (`'foo', 'bar'` alone will do).</sup>

Comment: Could having a large number of sessions cause it to cease operating? As far as performance goes it should be okay but if it could cause issues I'll need to change it.

Comment: Performance aside, using `@(...)` with a large number of sessions would only be a problem if you ran out of memory, which seems unlikely.